# JTree null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, jtree

If i put path to my CD drive it list all files and folders as it should, but if I put a path to a hard driver partition i get NullPointerException. Can some one help me with this. I can not get to the bottom of this. What is different between CD folders structures and partition structure O.o System.out.print is working fine for both CD and HDD partition. Here is a code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Anak1n
 */
public class gui extends JPanel {

    private final JTree tree;

    TreeModel model;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JButton load;
    File fileRoot = new File("F:/");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    public gui() {

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();

        getList(root, fileRoot);

        tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        add(new JScrollPane((JTree) tree), "Center");

    }

    public void getList(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, File f) {

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f);
            node.add(child);
            File fList[] = f.listFiles();
           for (File fList1 : fList) {
                getList(child, fList1); 
            }
        }

        if (f.isFile()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f);
            node.add(child);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but: My guess is that there are some Windows "directories" you cannot easily access. Therefore the listFiles method returns null. Skip said directories.

Comment: You are right. I get this when running program : S-1-5-18 . I SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID 
S-1-5-18

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem is in windows folder permission. This solves some of the problems:

```
if ( f.isDirectory() && !f.getName().equals("$RECYCLE.BIN") && !f.getName().equals("System Volume Information") && 
                !f.getName().equals("$Recycle.Bin") && !f.getName().equals("Config.Msi"))
```

But there is lot more locked files that can not be accessed.